# React adding FloatingMenuButton Package Parsing error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and trying to add the Floating Menu Button from [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-floating-button-menu) Package.

Adding this I get following Error.

> Parsing error: Unexpected token[image: Error]

I have uploaded the Code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/adding-floatingmenu-2tfxe?file=/src/App.js

I also have another Question. What is the difference of adding `render() {}` infront of `return()` or just leaving `return()`?

**Update**

I have Updated my Code inside codesandbox, there i do not receive an Error, after I copied it into VSCode i receive following error[image: Error].

Comment: You can not use react hooks in Class Components. Remove the useState hook and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use react hooks only in functional components. If you use class components you not allowed to use hooks.

> But what is a Hook?
> Hooks are functions that let you “hook into” React state and lifecycle features from function components. Hooks don’t work inside classes — they let you use React without classes.

2. Second question the same situation, render() uses in class components, in functional components you just use return(<></>)

Please read hooks owerview:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html

Answer (score -1):

If you want to initialize the isOpen state as false, here's a minimal example of that

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  FloatingMenu,
  MainButton,
  ChildButton,
} from "react-floating-button-menu";


export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    }
  }

  render() {
  return (
  <FloatingMenu
    slideSpeed={500}
    direction="up"
    spacing={8}
    isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
  >
    <MainButton
      backgroundColor="black"
      onClick={() => this.setState({ open: !this.state.isOpen })}
      size={56}
    />
  </FloatingMenu>
);
  }
};
```

Make sure you import Component from 'react' at the top. Render method is required when you're making a React component using a class method which you are using. It's a type of lifecycle method which is invoked when the component needs to update. The return statement only returns the data/JSX elements wherever it is being used.

If you are using functional components, you don't need a render method since they return the react elements themselves

Comment: First of all, thank you for you comment. I have Updated my Question because i got a new error and can't figure it out, what's wrong there.